# Firefox won't fire window.onfocus event after prolonged idle

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onfocus

I'm having trouble getting Firefox (and possibly Chrome too) to refresh a page on focus after a prolonged idle time.  Here is a snippet of the code I used:

```
var blurred = false;
window.onblur = function() {
  blurred = true;
}
window.onfocus = function() {
  blurred ? location.reload(): false;
}
```

It works well for while but if I tab back after some time (4 - 24 hours) it won't refresh the page.  Is there something that I am missing or not understanding?
Any help would be much appreciated!

This is on Firefox 61.01 operating on Windows 10.